# How find Selector by variable attr val

Tags: javascript, jquery

İf possible, I want to find `attr` selectors by `attr` name

```
$( "[value*='lng']" ).length // working
$( "[*='lng']" ).length // not working
$( "[.*='lng']" ).length  // not working
```

**How is it possible to find that by `attr` arg?**

for example:

```
  <input name="name" type="text"  placeholder="lng">
  <input name="name" type="text"  value="lng">
  <input name="lng" type="text" >
```

I need to find that selector by variable `attrName`.

Like this `$('*[*="lng"]');` if possible.

Comment: Your jQuery says "lng" and your code says "lang".

Comment: ops,  edited  thanks

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do and why you need to do this. Based on what you provided you are just looking to get the total amount of elements?

Comment: @EternalHour, I think OP wants to select all elements based on an attribute value. But, OP wants to check all attributes without hardcoding the attribute name.

Comment: @Kei - I ask because there's probably a much better way to accomplish it, such as data attributes.

Comment: @EternalHour, ah okay, sorry I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: It's an odd requirement. http://xyproblem.info/ instead of asking for a solution, you should explain why you need this, this may not be the correct way to attack the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a pure JavaScript function to get all elements which have either `placeholder`, `value` or `name` equal to your string and return them as an array. Is this generic enough for you?

```html
<input name="name" type="text"  placeholder="lng">
<input name="name" type="text"  value="lng">
<input name="lng" type="text" >

<script>
  const getAllInputContainingText = (text) => {
    let placeholderArray = document.querySelectorAll(`input[placeholder="${text}"]`)
    let valueArray = document.querySelectorAll(`input[value="${text}"]`)
    let nameArray = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${text}"]`)
    
    return [...placeholderArray, ...valueArray, ...nameArray]
  }
  
  console.log(getAllInputContainingText("lng"))
</script>
```

Comment: sure, but i want  find all of it
for example : $('* [*="lng"]');

Comment: Is the number of fields variable? Because if it's not you can probably just write a selector for each one of them. Example: `$('input[value="lng"]');`, `$('input[name="lng"]');` and `$('input[placeholder="lng"]');`.

Comment: thats right, number of fields are variable and attr names variable

Comment: I changed my answer to a function that gets all input containing either placeholder, value or name equal to a given string and returns them as an array. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: This should be a single query with three selectors separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible through a jQuery selector. In the documentation, there is no provision for wildcard attributes.

See: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

You could use a different approach though. For example, you could select all elements, then apply a filter. You could run into performance issues using this method though.

```
function selectByAttrVal(value) {
    return $("*").filter((index,ele) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < ele.attributes.length; i++) {
            if (ele.attributes[i].value === value) return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery filter function and check all attributes.

```
$('input').filter(function() {
      return Object.values(this.attributes).find((attr) => attr.value == 'lng')
  }).length;
```